# Grafana Spring Boot Dashboard Application variable sets to "None"

Tags: grafana, spring-boot-actuator

I imported grafana JVM Micrometer dashboard id: 10731. However, Application variable on the dashboard is showing as “None”

Anyone here has experience as to how to make the Application variable contains actual application name? Source is data is prometheus.

Attached is screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Probably no records have the label `application` set.

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: APPLICATION_NAME
```

If it doesn't work, then reload data sources on Grafana